# When changing call order of UIElement.CaptureMouse() on Canvas containing two Image, I get different result

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm now just trying to create a simple image viewer with panning and zooming, for studying WPF.

I wrote my XAML code like this:

```
<Window x:Class="PanningImageTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PanningImageTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border Name="panBorder" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Canvas Name="panImage" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"
                MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <!-- Two Image is intended, as in real situation,
                     they will use different sources -->
                <Image Source="Wallpaper.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
                <Image Source="Wallpaper.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And wrote my code like this:
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;

```
namespace PanningImageTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Point _start;
        private Point _origin;

        private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.panImage.CaptureMouse();

            _start = e.GetPosition(this.panBorder);
            _origin.X = this.panImage.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
            _origin.Y = this.panImage.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY;
        }

        private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.panImage.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                return;
            }

            Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(this.panBorder);

            Matrix matrix = this.panImage.RenderTransform.Value;
            matrix.OffsetX = _origin.X + (mousePos.X - _start.X);
            matrix.OffsetY = _origin.Y + (mousePos.Y - _start.Y);

            this.panImage.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
        }

        private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.panImage.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `this.panImage.CaptureMouse()` **BEFORE** the `_start = ... etc ...` lines, All the Images just teleports to the position of the mouse as soon as I clicked somewhere on the image.

Like this:
[Call before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdqw2.gif)

But if I call the same function **after** the lines, like the following, it just works as intended:

```
    _start = e.GetPosition(this.panBorder);
    _origin.X = this.panImage.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
    _origin.Y = this.panImage.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY;

    this.panImage.CaptureMouse();
```

Like this:
[Call After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfb8O.gif)

If I use only one `Image` tag in `Canvas`, it works nicely in both cases.
I tried changing .NET versions, moving events to `Border` instead of `Canvas`, but everything just failed to explain these results.

I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone give some explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseMove` event has started to be fired even the `MouseLeftButtonDown` method has not yet finished.

So you call `CaptureMouse() method` as the last line, and use the following check as a guard to prevent the image from being dragged when you have not yet gotten the value of **_origin**.

```
if (!this.panImage.IsMouseCaptured)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: That's a great explanation. But I have a question. If I get rid of Canvas in XAML, and only leave one Image, like <Border><Image/></Border>, and handle mouse event on Image, like <Image MouseLeftButtonDown=.../>, it works even if I call CaptureMouse on Image first, before calculating the value of _origin. Is it just a fortune? or some mechanism?

Comment: The difference is: When you click the image and try to capture the mouse to the _underlying Canvas_, the Canvas's MouseMove event is triggered. On contrast, when you click the image and try to capture the image, the image's MouseMove event is not fired. Looks like this is caused by the CaptureMouse API. This is a very interesting symptom, I suggest you ask a seperate question why the MouseMove is triggered in the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the start position and the coordinates *before* you start to calculate the offsets. Otherwise you get the offsets wrong. So it makes no sense to capture the mouse before you have done this.

Note that the `MouseMove` event will be raised as soon as you move the mouse(all the time basically) but until you have captured it, the event handler will just return without moving the image by setting its `RenderTransform` property.

So you should set the start position and the X and Y coordinates and then move the image based on these. Not the other way around.